# New object from class out of a list of classes

Tags: java

I have this small program that I'm working on where a user types in a string and the program searches the string for a command that matches. I'm trying to make it so that I can add new commands without a wall of text.

Every time I want a new command I have to go into my CommandCore class and call registercommand(new command())

I thought maybe I could make a list of the command classes and stick it in a loop which could make new objects and add them to a map. However eclipse is moaning saying that "new cmdClass()" cannot be resolved to a type.

```
registerCommand(new Help()) //<-- I could have 50 of these or...

for (Class<Command> cmdClass : CommandClass) {
    registerCommand(new cmdClass());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

(This is the registerCommand method)

```
public static void registerCommand(Command cmdObj) {
    CommandMap.put(cmdObj.commandName, cmdObj);
    HelpMap.put(cmdObj.commandName, cmdObj.helpString);
}
```

Comment: And how are you planning to fill the `CommandClass` list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `registerCommand(cmdClass.newInstance());`